# Periodically running btrfs-scrub

Tags: arch-linux, systemd, btrfs, manjaro, systemd-timer

The `btrfs-scrub` manpage says:

> The user is supposed to run it manually or via a periodic system
>   service. The recommended period is a month but could be less.

For `systemd` users how is this automated, capturing all output in the journal?

I am running Manjaro based on Arch Linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Being a [virtuously lazy](http://threevirtues.com/) sysadmin, I came up with the following which will start and enable the `btrfs-scrub@XXX.timer` on all currently mounted `btrfs` filesystems:

```
awk '$3=="btrfs" { system("systemd-escape " $2 "| cut -c2-") }' /etc/fstab | while read -r fs; do
    [[ -z $fs ]] && fs=- # Set to '-' for the root FS
    sudo systemctl enable btrfs-scrub@"$fs".timer
    sudo systemctl start btrfs-scrub@"$fs".timer
done
```

Credit to @Head_on_a_Stick for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: Where does this need to go? Run once in a console? Put somewhere where it will be called at start-up? ...

Comment: @Zak once at console to enable / start the systemd unit.

Comment: What is wrong? 

`user@inspiron:~$ awk '$3=="btrfs" { system("systemd-escape " $2 "| cut -c2-") }' /etc/fstab | while read -r fs; do
>     [[ -z $fs ]] && fs=- # Set to '-' for the root FS
>     sudo systemctl enable btrfs-scrub@"$fs".timer
>     sudo systemctl start btrfs-scrub@"$fs".timer
> done
Failed to enable unit: Unit file btrfs-scrub@-.timer does not exist.
Failed to start btrfs-scrub@-.timer: Unit btrfs-scrub@-.timer not found.
Failed to enable unit: Unit file btrfs-scrub@home.timer does not exist.
Failed to start btrfs-scrub@home.timer: Unit btrfs-scrub@home.timer...`

Answer (score 5):

Arch Linux supplies btrfs-progs with a .timer unit file for `btrfs-scrub` that can be activated with:

`systemctl enable btrfs-scrub@-.timer`

The dash ("-") after the @ symbol is used to indicate the root directory, see the ArchWiki page for more on this:

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Btrfs#Start_with_a_service_or_timer

To check the status, use:

`systemctl list-timers`

Or:

`journalctl -u btrfs-scrub@-.{timer,service}`

Comment: Thanks - can't believe I missed that part in the wiki. Perhaps others will too.